# How to upgrade to RDP 8.0 on Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I recently saw the Microsoft blog entry describing the new features of RDP 8.0 and how to enable this new functionality.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2592687

I successfully upgraded a Win7 Ultimate (x64) and Win7 Enterprise (x64) machine following these instructions.  I also have a Win7 Home Premium (x64) machine which obviously does not have the "Local Group Policy Editor" and the instructions only reference policies and not registry entries.

I eventually took snapshots of my registry on my Win7 Ultimate machine before and after changing the policies to determine the registries keys changed.  Here are the keys I noted and tried incorporating into my Win7 Home Premium machine which did not work.

---

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\TerminalServices]

"fServerEnableRDP8"=dword:00000001

"SelectTransport"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows
   NT\Terminal Services]

"fServerEnableRDP8"=dword:00000001

"SelectTransport"=dword:00000000

---

Any thoughts, ideas, or instructions for next steps would be appreciated.  (UDP support and a resizable connection bar alone make this a worthwhile update for me!)

Sincerely,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

I got to thinking about the order of the prerequisite hot-fix and the subsequent update in terms on my Win7 Home Premium machine.  I went back, uninstalled both patches, reinstalled both patches in the correct order and everything is working as intended now.  I may have also had remote desktop running when I applied the patches, possibly preventing an update even though it does a reboot for system files.

More info from a different thread I started over at technet:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/2b8021df-7944-401d-ba21-606308bb9219

Answer (score 1):

I went on to the Microsoft site as I also had all the correct fixes and protocols and still couldn't get remote access to work. One of the responses said that a lot of people were using Team Viewer. I have just installed it on both of our laptops and it worked immediately. Awesome software.